# ng-click or called method doesn't work

Tags: html, angularjs, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to call a method in Angular but it doesn't work and I don't know why

This is my HTML

```
 <div class="panel-footer text-right">
     <input type="button" ng-click="AceptarSolicitudPendiente()" class="btn btn-primary"  value="Guardar" />
 </div>
```

and this is my JS

```
  s.AceptarSolicitudPenediente = function () {
      var config = {
          method: "POST",
          url: "CatSolicitud.aspx/GuardarLOG",
          data: {
              Log: {
                  IdSolicitud: s.solicitudSeleccionada.Id_Sol,
                  FechaCompromiso: $("#FechaCompromiso").val(),
                  Comentario: s.Comentario,
                  Estatus: "Activo",
                  Motivo: null
              }
          }
      };

      h(config).success(function (data, status, head, conf) {
          data = $.parseJSON(data.d);

          if (data.success) {
              s.closeAceptar();
              s.message = data.message;
              s.openModal();
              s.loadSolicitud();
          } else {
              s.message = data.message;
              s.openModal();
          }
      }).error(function (data, status, head, conf) {
          console.log(data);
      });
  }
```

It should work because I have another method to do another action and it works, but not this. I'm tired of search any error or something but no, I can't find anything.

Comment: How do you know it's not getting called? Have you put a console.log in the function to see if it is called? Have you opened your developer console and investigated if there's any errors being thrown?

Comment: Is s a $scope in your controller ? and also please post your complete app.js or main.js file in  gist or snippet file if possible.
And also remove () for ng-click scope variable.

Comment: What is `s`? What does your ngController directive look like? If the function isn't getting called, we really don't need to see the entire content of it. Focus on the *problem*, not the extraneous detail of the code.

Comment: app.controller('consultaSolicitudController', ["$scope", "$http", function (s, h) {

this is "s".

sorry dudes, thanks for the reply but i found my mistake.

I just calling a different function, well, only different name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found my mistake, I was writting different name Function.

I was calling **AceptarSolicitudPendiente()** and It was **AceptarSolicitudPenediente()**

Thank you guys.